# How can SQLite command ".import" read directly from standard input?

Tags: bash, shell-script, io-redirection, csv, sqlite

How would you modify function `csv_to_sqlite` so that [`sqlite3`](https://sqlite.org/cli.html) command [`.import`](https://sqlite.org/cli.html#importing_csv_files) reads directly from standard input instead of from a temporary named pipe?

```
#!/bin/bash

function csv_to_sqlite() {
  local database_file_name="$1"
  local table_name="$2"
  local temp_input_fifo=$(mktemp -u)
  mkfifo $temp_input_fifo
  sqlite3 -csv $database_file_name ".import $temp_input_fifo $table_name" &
  cat > $temp_input_fifo
  rm $temp_input_fifo
}

database_file_name=$1
table_name=$2

csv_to_sqlite "$database_file_name" "$table_name"
```

```
$ printf "col1,col2,col3\na,1,2.6\nb,2,5.4\n" | ./csv_to_sqlite test.sqlite test
$ sqlite3 -csv -header test.sqlite "SELECT * FROM test"
col1,col2,col3
a,1,2.6
b,2,5.4
```

Comment: Would `.import /dev/stdin $table_name` work? (Depending on your OS, you might need to replace `/dev/stdin` with `/dev/fd/0` or something like that.)

Comment: @GordonDavisson Yes, `/dev/stdin` would work, but I wanted to avoid referring to files that might be non-standard.

Comment: @fra-san Since they are using `bash`, the existence of `/dev/stdin` is guaranteed (it's provided by the shell if it does not already exist). Care to write up an answer?

Comment: I found another [solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/642362/5783) that doesn't read `/dev/stdin` or a temporary named pipe.

Comment: @DerekMahar Great! No need to add other answers, then.

Comment: @fra-san Also, since it's the `sqlite` process accessing the file, not `bash`, there is no guarantee about `/dev/stdin` existing (although, there is _very few_ systems that does not have it).

Comment: @fra-san Not sure if this is a corner case one should care about, but Bash dealing with `/dev/stdin` etc. itself seems to be a compile time option. So if you have a system that should support have it, but the file is broken, Bash won't help you there.

Comment: @ilkkachu I wouldn't know either, but, as Kusalananda pointed out, it is indeed not relevant in this case (good point in general, though). -- I'll start removing up my comments here, they're not helpful anymore (and possibly misleading...).

Comment: `/dev/stdin` blows up memory if the file is too large for memory unfortunately.

Answer (score 14):

I found another solution that still uses [`sqlite3`](https://sqlite.org/cli.html) [`.import`](https://sqlite.org/cli.html#importing_csv_files), but that doesn't read `/dev/stdin` or a temporary named pipe.  Instead, it uses `.import` with the [pipe operator](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#reading_sql_from_a_file) to invoke `cat -` to read directly from standard input.

```
#!/bin/bash

function csv_to_sqlite() {
  local database_file_name="$1"
  local table_name="$2"
  sqlite3 -csv $database_file_name ".import '|cat -' $table_name"
}

database_file_name=$1
table_name=$2

csv_to_sqlite "$database_file_name" "$table_name"
```

Comment: well, I should have read the manual better the first time.

Comment: @ilkkachu This solution wasn't obvious because, unfortunately, the [`.import`](https://sqlite.org/cli.html#importing_csv_files) documentation doesn't mention the `|` operator.  As you discovered, you have to read the [`.read`](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#reading_sql_from_a_file) documentation to discover the `|` operator.

Comment: @ilkkachu I moved your link to the `sqlite3` [`.read`](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#reading_sql_from_a_file) command to the first paragraph as an inline link.

Comment: @ilkkachu It is very subtle in the docs!  `The source argument is the name of a file to be read or, if it begins with a "|" character, specifies a command which will be run to produce the input CSV data.`  Ref: https://sqlite.org/cli.html#importing_csv_files

Comment: @kevinarpe An SQLite contributor added this reference to the pipe character to the documentation for the `.import` command on 2021-04-01, just a few days after @ikkachu and I made our comments.  See https://www.sqlite.org/cgi/docsrc/info/7652db76ff667908.